# Como acceder a sub objetos en Angular y Firebase con @angular/fire

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente objeto desde mi realtime database en firebase y lo que quisiera hacer es poner todos los productos de los restaurantes en un mismo arreglo de datos para asi darles posteriormente un orden.

```json
[
  {
    "Restaurant 1": {
      "Productos": {
        "0e4ef4dc-623c-4729-96d3-a2269c8a3605": {
          "name": "Pizza",
          "category": "pizzas"
        },
        "10a22e40-e35b-4090-be28-5c24a7e680ec": {
          "name": "Hamburguesa",
          "category": "burguers"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Restaurant 2": {
      "Productos": {
        "0e4ef4dc-623c-4729-96d3-a2269c8a3605": {
          "name": "Coca Cola",
          "category": "drinks"
        },
        "10a22e40-e35b-4090-be28-5c24a7e680ec": {
          "name": "Ensalada",
          "category": "salad"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Este es mi componente

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StoreService } from '../../../services/store/store.service';
import { Product } from '../../../models/product.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[] = [];

  constructor(private storeService: StoreService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.storeService.getProducts().on("value", snap =>{
      this.products = [];
      snap.forEach((child: any) => {
        this.products.push(child.val());
      });
    });
  }
  
}
```

Hasta aqui todo bien, obtengo los valores desde la realtime, pero el objeto que se almacena es el que se ve en el json de más arriba, yo quisiera saltarme el nivel de Restaurant X y obtener los valores de "Productos".

Resultado esperado

```json
[
  {
    "0e4ef4dc-623c-4729-96d3-a2269c8a3605": {
      "name": "Pizza",
      "category": "pizzas"
    },
    "10a22e40-e35b-4090-be28-5c24a7e680ec": {
      "name": "Hamburguesa",
      "category": "burguers"
    },
    "0124e4dc-623c-4729-96d3-a2269c8a3605": {
      "name": "Coca Cola",
      "category": "drinks"
    },
    "10423e40-e35b-4090-be28-5c24a7e680ec": {
      "name": "Ensalada",
      "category": "salad"
    }
  }
]
```

Agradezco respuestas constructivas :)

Comment: Dado que `Productos` no es un array, puedes usar `Object.keys(child.Productos).forEach((key) => this.products.push(child.Productos[key]))` o algo así. :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Benito, estaba utilizando Spread Operator, pero en temas de rendimiento no era lo óptimo. Probaré tu solución en unos minutos.